# Storage capacity of in-memory database?

Tags: database, in-memory-database

Is storage capacity of in-memory database limited to size of RAM? If yes, is there any ways to increase its capacity except for increasing RAM size. If no, please give some explanations.

Comment: Well, where else would it be stored?

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, in-memory storage capacity is limited by the **addressable memory**, not by the amount of physical memory in the system.  Simon was also correct that the OS will swap memory to the page file, but you *really* want to avoid that.  In the context of the DBMS, the OS will do a worse job of it than if you simply used a persistent database with as large of a cache as you have physical memory to support.  IOW, the DBMS will manage its cache more intelligently than the OS would manage paged memory containing in-memory database content.

Answer (score 0):

On a 32 bit system, each process is limited to a total of 3GB of RAM, whether you have 3GB physically or 512MB. If you have more data (including the in-mem DB) and code then will fit into physical RAM then the Page file on disc is used to swap out memory that is currently not being used. Swapping does slow everything down though. There are some tricks you can use for extending that: Memory-mapped files, /3GB switch; but these are not easy to implement.

On 64 bit machines, a processes memory limitation is huge - I forget what it is but it's up in the TB range.

Answer (score 0):

VoltDB is an in-memory SQL database that runs on a cluster of 64-bit Linux servers.  It has high performance durability to disk for recovery purposes, but tables, indexes and materialized views are stored 100% in-memory.  A VoltDB cluster can be expanded on the fly to increase the overall available RAM and throughput capacity without any down time.  In a high-availability configuration, individual nodes can also be stopped to perform maintenance such as increasing the server's RAM, and then rejoined to the cluster without any down time.

The design of VoltDB, led by Michael Stonebraker, was for a no-compromise approach to performance and scalability of OLTP transaction processing workloads with full ACID guarantees.  Today these workloads are often described as Fast Data.  By using main memory, and single-threaded SQL execution code distributed for parallel processing by core, the data can be accessed as fast as possible in order to minimize the execution time of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

There are in-memory solutions that can work with data sets larger than RAM. Of course, this is accomplished by adding some operations on disk. Tarantool's *Vinyl*, for example, can work with data sets that are 10 to 1000 times the size of available RAM. [Like](http://www.benstopford.com/2015/02/14/log-structured-merge-trees/) other databases of recent vintage such as RocksDB and Bigtable, *Vinyl's* write algorithm uses LSM trees instead of B trees, which helps with its speed.